# Has evelated user through SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriviliges write permissions to SharePoint LOGS folder?

Tags: 2013, 2010, logging

i have a general question:

When i run my under

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges
```

Does the eleveated user (AppPool Account) always (in any SP installation) permission to create a file in the Sharepoint SharePoint Root\LOGS folder?

Comment: do you asked...does Elevated permission i.e App Pool account always has permission to write in the ULS Logs file? or if you run any code under elevated privilage account

Comment: in both cases the answer is yes.

Comment: @Waqas: Isnt it both times the same?